# How to wait for a docker container to exit/timeout when it reaches the completion

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a JenkinsFile where i have a postgresql container running. But i need to write a logic which will wait for the docker container to timout/exit.

Currently, i have something like this

```
psql_container=sh(script: "docker inspect psqlcont --format='{{.State.ExitCode}}'", returnStdout: true).trim()

sh "sleep 1000"

if (psql_container != '0'){
                    error "psql failed ..."
                }else{
                 echo "psql starts"
```

Instead of sleep, i need to write a condition where the container will quit/timeout in 1000 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

The [`docker wait`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/wait/) command will wait (indefinitely) for a container to complete.  The Jenkins pipeline [`timeout`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#timeout-enforce-time-limit) step will run some block but abort after a deadline.  You can combine these to wait for a container to finish, or kill it if it takes too long:

```groovy
try {
  timeout(1000, unit: SECONDS) {
    sh "docker wait psqlcont"
  }
} catch(e) {
  sh "docker stop psqlcont"
  sh "docker wait psqlcont" // <= 10s, container is guaranteed to be stopped
}
sh "docker rm psqlcont"
```

Comment: Thanks @David Maze, In my scenario there is a docker container ( similar to psql) which will populate the tables and then gets exited. Is it possible to check wait till container reaches exit status and then go to next step? How do we do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `timeout` command, instead of sleep,

`timeout [OPTIONS] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]…`
Copy
The DURATION can be a positive integer or a floating-point number, followed by an optional unit suffix:

s - seconds (default)
m - minutes
h - hours
d - days

You can send a command when the `timeout` time has been reached also,

For example, to send SIGKILL to the ping command after one minute, you would use:

`sudo timeout -s SIGKILL ping 8.8.8.8`